# document.createElement in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, client-side

What is the proper way to create a new client element through javascript in an asp.net page?  Also, is it possible to move already created elements inside of the new element without causing too much havoc?  Either straight javascript or jquery will work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using jquery, because it abstracts out the browser inconsistencies. In jquery, you would use something like:

```
$('<div>').appendTo('#parent'); // parent is the id of the outer element
```

to create a new div element. You can use appendTo to add this element inside another dom element. Refer jquery documentation at http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: Will this work without messing up the inherent .net control structure?

Comment: Yes. However, ASP.Net controls (<asp:xxx runat="server">) generate the "id" when the ASP.Net engine creates the HTML different from what you specified in the markup and so the client side jquery code will not be able to access them without the full id, unless you use the attribute ClientIDMode="static", which makes sure that the id at design time and runtime are same. Alternately, you can set the CssClass property and use the jquery class selector as shown here http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/. Please mark it as an answer if it helped solve your problem.

Comment: I will but this didn't quite fix my problem.  Using append, wrap, or wrapinner from jquery is wiping out the Sys.Application._components array in the .net framework.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you give me some more information on what version of ASP.Net you are using? And what is the exact scenario when you want to create a new element? Also, please do note that if you add a control from client side, you will not be able to access it from the code-behind. You can only get the value of the control from the Request variables.

Comment: I'm not trying to access it from the code behind.  I'm attempting to access it from javascript using .Net AJAX's $find function.  ($find uses Sys.Application._components to return objects).  I'm wrapping the contents of an iframe in a div (turning <body></body> into <body><div /></body>)

Comment: I haven't worked much on the ASP.Net AJAX controls, but I would think that to be able to be added to _components collection, it should be an AJAX control / component. You might want to create an AJAX control, and add it using the $create function. Something on the line of http://mosesofegypt.net/post/BuildingjQueryAndASPNetAJAXEnabledControlsjQueryCollapsiblePanelExtenderPart1.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to do something that intense for just adding a div to the page.  The problem moreso is that the controls are being removed when the div is added.  I've been looking and can't find any information on why that's happening.